# Number of days in leap years with IsoChronology

Tags: java, java-time, days, period, date-difference

2000 CE is a leap year with 366 days.
2001 CE and 2002 CE do not leap years and have 355 days.

Logically, if I ask the number of days between January 1st, 2000 CE and January 1st, 2001 CE, I should get one more day than between January 1st, 2001 CE and January 1st, 2002 CE.

This is not what I observe, see code below.

```java
        IsoChronology isoc = IsoChronology.INSTANCE;

        LocalDate date1;
        LocalDate date2;
        Period period;

        // Between January 1st, 0 CE and January 1st, 1 CE

        date1 = isoc.dateYearDay(2000, 1);
        date2 = isoc.dateYearDay(2001, 1);
        period = Period.between(date1, date2);

        assertTrue(isoc.isLeapYear(2000L));
        assertFalse(isoc.isLeapYear(2001L));
        assertEquals("2000-01-01", date1.toString());
        assertEquals("2001-01-01", date2.toString());
        assertEquals("P1Y", period.toString());

        // Between January 1st, 1 CE and January 1st, 2 CE

        date1 = isoc.dateYearDay(2001, 1);
        date2 = isoc.dateYearDay(2002, 1);
        period = Period.between(date1, date2);

        assertFalse(isoc.isLeapYear(2001L));
        assertFalse(isoc.isLeapYear(2002L));
        assertEquals("2001-01-01", date1.toString());
        assertEquals("2002-01-01", date2.toString());
        assertEquals("P1Y", period.toString());
```

**EDIT**

Modified the example to use 400 CE, 401 CE and 402 CE since 0 CE is not a "real" year (1 BCE and 1 CE are real, but 0 BCE = 1 CE and 1 BCE = 0 CE).

**EDIT**

Modified the examples to use 2000 CE, 2001 CE and 2002 CE to use years in the (non-proleptic) Gregorian calendar.

Additionally removed irrelevant information.

**EDIT**

`Period.toString()` includes the days when they are not 0. `Period.of(1 /* year /, 0 / month /, 1 / days */)` renders as `P1Y1D`, so I would have expected one of the example to be different from the other one.

**COMPLEMENT**

According to the ISO chronology and Period, one month and one day after January 28th 2001 is March 1st 2001. But one month and one day before that date is January 31st 2001.

So in this case we end up 3 days later than where we started from.

On a leap year, we would end up on the same date in this case.

```java
        IsoChronology chronology = IsoChronology.INSTANCE;

        Period oneMonthOneDay = Period.of(0, 1, 1);

        Temporal january28th2001 = chronology.date(2001, 1, 28);
        Temporal march1st2001 = oneMonthOneDay.addTo(january28th2001);
        Temporal january31th2001 = oneMonthOneDay.subtractFrom(march1st2001);
        Assert.assertEquals("2001-01-28", january28th2001.toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("2001-03-01", march1st2001.toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("2001-01-31", january31th2001.toString());

        Temporal january28th2004 = chronology.date(2004, 1, 28);
        Temporal february29th2004 = oneMonthOneDay.addTo(january28th2004);
        Temporal january28th2004Again = oneMonthOneDay.subtractFrom(february29th2004);
        Assert.assertEquals("2004-01-28", january28th2004.toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("2004-02-29", february29th2004.toString());
        Assert.assertEquals("2004-01-28", january28th2004Again.toString());
```

Comment: Hint for future date/time work: I'd suggest using modern years (e.g. 2004, 2005). Otherwise you need to at least consider whether the calendar observes the Julian/Gregorian cutover.

Comment: Yes, the ISO chronology uses the proleptic gregorian calendar which is an extension of the gregorian calendar to the past, so 400 is indeed a leap year according to this calendar (and 0 CE is well defined).
Technically the Julian/Gregorian cutover date is actually dependent on the location, the change happened in 1582 in France but in 1923 in Greece for example, and one would have to use the geopolitical frontiers of the time to actually map a location to the corresponding country, so being historically precise is quite complicated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of all of that. My point is that your question doesn't rely on this at all - so it's best to use a simpler situation, e.g. 2004 and 2005. That way the reader *doesn't* need to be aware of the lack of cutover in the proleptic calendar.

Comment: I would suggest that 2000 is *also* an unfortunate choice, given that it's a special case of "divisible by 100, but also by 400". Again, there's nothing incorrect about using it - it just takes more thinking about. There's a reason why I suggested 2004 and 2005...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically not wrong. Between 2000-01-01 and 2001-01-01, it is the period of "1 year" ("P1Y"). Between 2001-01-01 and 2002-01-01, it is *also* the period of "1 year" ("P1Y"). *Nowhere* does it say 365 or 366 *days*. You can't actually get the number 365 or 366 from the `period` you've got.

You are not asking how many *days* there are, between the two dates here:

```
Period.between(date1, date2)
```

You are asking for the period.

A `Period` is a number of years, months and days, and you just so happen to get the period of "1 year 0 months 0 days" as the output.

Note that period calculations are very different from those you are used to in maths. Adding "1 month" to the Feb 1 adds 28 or 29 days, but adding "1 month" to March 1 adds 30 days. This also means that adding "1 month" 10 times to a date could give you a different result than adding "10 months" all in one go.

You might be wondering why doesn't `Period.between` give you the number of days between the dates, but rather just says "1 year". First, note that "1 year" and "365 days" are very different periods. Adding "1 year" to 2020-01-01 would give you 2021-01-01, but adding "365 days" to 2020-01-01 would give you 2020-12-31.

If `Period.between` returned "365 days" or "366 days" instead, you wouldn't be able to, e.g. easily ask the user to input two dates, and continue to output dates at that interval. Consider:

```
public void iterateDatesAtRegularInterval(LocalDate date1, LocalDate date2) {
    Period p = Period.between(date1, date2);
    LocalDate current = date2;
    while (some end condition) {
        current = current.plus(p);
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

If `Period.between` returned "365 days" or "366 days" instead and I happen to pass 2020-01-01 and 2021-01-01 (366 days), the next thing this method would output would be 2022-01-02, which IMO would be quite unexpected for most people.

`Period.between` basically picks the largest units that it can, because this is most likely going to be the most useful to you, if you are doing period calculations.

If you want the result of 365/366 days though, don't use `Period`. Use something like:

```
assertEquals(365L, ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2))
```

Comment: That's a very useful response thank you, I understand the use case for Period now.
It seems that it is well defined when only years, only months, or only days are in the period. If I add a period of 2 month and 30 days, or 3 years, 2 month and 30 days, with february in between having 28 or 29 days, I am not sure the end result is very intuitive. I'll have a look later.

Comment: @Gzorg [See the definition of "adding" here. Everything is specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#addTo-java.time.temporal.Temporal-). Months and years are added together, then the days are added. As for intuitiveness, well, you'd get used to it :)

Comment: Thanks for the doc, I find documentation very useful as a reminder, for things that I have already gotten used to. But here I must say that I read this, and I still need to do some experiments and modify my mental model to fit the results ;).